# Conditions for Poisson approximation of the superposition of non-Poisson processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, asymptotics, point-process, poisson-process, heuristic

It is [well known](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17320/mixing-and-dividing-point-processes/17346#17346) that the superposition of $N$ Poisson processes is itself a Poisson process with an intensity given by 
$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \lambda _{n}$.

Conversely a superposition including any non-Poisson component processes is not Poisson.

However, the superposition of
sparse processes converges to a Poisson process 
 as $N\rightarrow \infty $  and as the sparseness increases. This is referred to on Wikipedia as the [Palm-Khintchine theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm%E2%80%93Khintchine_theorem): a recent paper with discussion of the original work is given by [Schuhmacher 2005](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414905000803).

If I have a collection of sampled processes, the superposition of which is well modeled as a Poisson process, under what conditions of $N$ & $\hat{\lambda_{n}}$ can I conclude that all component processes are Poisson?

P.S. 
This problem is known and has been studied in queuing theory. [Newell 1984](http://mansci.journal.informs.org/content/30/5/623) provides a condition that if the component arrival processes satisfy $n(1-\rho)^2 {\gg } 1$, where $\rho$ is the utilisation, then the queue will approximate a  M/M/1 queue (Poisson arrival process). How does this formula apply to the more general problem outlined above?

Comment: Unless you know of some underlying structure to the component processes, I think you are going to have to check each one to see if it is Poisson. As an example of a useful structure where you could avoid this, if you knew the superposition process was Poisson and the sub-processes were defined by a splitting mechanism, then you may be able to immediately know the sub-processes are also Poisson. Look up splitting a Poisson process if this is unfamiliar.